# How to handle json response from php?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm sending a ajax request to update database records, it test it using html form, its working fine, but when i tried to send ajax request its working, but the response I received is always null. where as on html form its show correct response. I'm using xampp on Windows OS. Kindly guide me in right direction.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $prov= $_POST['prov'];
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost';
    $myPDO = new PDO($dsn, 'admin', '1234');

    $selectSql = "SELECT abcd FROM xyz WHERE prov='".mysql_real_escape_string($prov)."'";
    $selectResult = $myPDO->query($selectSql);

    $row = $selectResult->fetch();
    $incr=intval($row['votecount'])+1;

    $updateSql = "UPDATE vote SET lmno='".$incr."' WHERE prov='".mysql_real_escape_string($prov)."'";
    $updateResult = $myPDO->query($updateSql);

    if($updateResult !== False) 
    {
    echo json_encode("Done!");
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo json_encode("Try Again!");
    }
    ?>




function increase(id)
    {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: { prov: id },
            success: function (response) {

            },
            complete: function (response) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                alert(obj);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: You're just returning a string, you don't need to `json_encode` it, just make your `dataType : "text"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: { prov: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                // you should recieve your responce data here
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                alert(obj);
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                //complete() is called always when the request is complete, no matter the outcome so you should avoid to recieve data in this function
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                alert(obj);
            }
        });
```

`complete` and the `success` function get different data passed in. `success` gets only the data, complete the whole `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your ajax request, you'll want to set `dataType` to `json` to ensure jQuery understands it is receiving json.

Secondly, `complete` is not passed the data from the ajax request, only `success` is.

Here is a full working example I put together, which I *know* works:

**test.php** (call this page in your web browser)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Define the javascript function
  function increase(id) {
    var post_data = {
      'prov': id
    }

    $.ajax({
      'type': 'POST',
      'url': 'ajax.php',
      'data': post_data,
      'dataType': 'json',
      'success': function (response, status, jQueryXmlHttpRequest) {
        alert('success called for ID ' + id + ', here is the response:');
        alert(response);
      },
      'complete': function(jQueryXmlHttpRequest, status) {
        alert('complete called');
      }
    });
  }

  // Call the function
  increase(1); // Simulate an id which exists
  increase(2); // Simulate an id which doesn't exist
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['prov'];

if($id == '1') { 
  $response = 'Done!';
} else {
  $response = 'Try again!';
}

print json_encode($response);
```

Comment: no error! i'm wondering why its working fine on html form! and not working with ajax request :(